# Typeorm MySql search by "column like %var%"

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

How to search in MySql using typeorm by using "column like".

```
 async findAll({
    page,
    count,
    ...where
  }: CategorySelectFilter): Promise<Category[]> {
    return this.categoryRepository.find({
      where,
      take: count,
      skip: (page - 1) * count,
      order: {
        createdAt: 'DESC',
      },
    });
  }
```

When "where" contains name it shoild search it by "name like %var_name%" and not just "name = var_name".

I need something like hook @BeforeLoad to override the name prop in entity.

I tried using @Index({fullText: false}) on name column, but it does not work.

Comment: What is ```where```??? Please add more information.

Comment: Just an object. {name:"...", ...}.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that I always use in my projects.

I use conditional [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (...) to "build" the query dynamically. See [this](https://www.sanity.io/blog/how-to-conditionally-build-an-object-in-es6) for more information.

```js
async findAll({
    page,
    count,
    whereConditions
}: CategorySelectFilter): Promise<Category[]> {
    return this.categoryRepository.find({
        ...whereConditions,
        take: count,
        skip: (page - 1) * count,
        order: {
            createdAt: 'DESC',
        },
        where: {
            ...(whereConditions.name !== undefined && { name: ILike(`%${whereConditions.name}%`) }),
        }
    });
}
```

The `where` condition *name: "%VARIABLE%"* is added only if `name` is present in `whereConditions` object.

PS: I prefer using `ILike`: can be used instead of `Like` to make the match *case-insensitive* according to the active locale.

Comment: This probably will work, but what I wanted is to put this code inside the entity, not in that specific query. Because if I want to use this in another query I have to copy paste it, or separate it in function. The best solution is somehow to use it in the entity. 


Something like:
@BeforeLoad()
beforeSelect(where){
if(where.name) where.name = ILike(`%${where.name}%`);
}

But there is no hook in typeorm to call before select

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1601#issuecomment-698834060).